# MVC passing data from model to view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

Actually I have a controller action and it gets the value of the variable 'result' from the function in a model. The action is as below.

```
if (model.buildingID == 0)
{
    var result = objAddBuildingBusinessModel.AddBuilding(model, connectionstring,isUnique);                       
}
else
{
    var result = objAddBuildingBusinessModel.UpdateBuilding(model, connectionstring);
}
```

So now based on the value of the variable 'result' I have to display a error message in the view if the value of variable 'result' is false.  Where in view should I display that and how should I do it . Please help me as I am new to MVC

Comment: error message from javascript or html div?

Comment: using javascript.

Comment: A quick way would be to use the ViewBag (i.e., ViewBag.result = result, make sure that result is in scope). Then on view add @ViewBag.result to display the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you can create a model to keep same information then your data send to view any transfer method and show Exception.

**EnumClass**

> Create Class EnumDefinitions. You can use all enum on this class
>   inside. Write all enums in namespace. You can access this
>   `OperationEnum.FAIL` or `OperationEnum.SUCCESS`

```
    [Obsolete("Dont Use", true)]
    internal static class EnumDefinitions
    {
       // dont use this.
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Operation Enums
    /// </summary>
    public enum OperationEnum
    {
        FAIL = 0,
        SUCCESS = 1,
    }
```

**Create Model**

```
public class OperationResult
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Operation fail code
    /// </summary>
    public static string FAIL = "0";

    /// <summary>
    /// Operation success code
    /// </summary>
    public static string SUCCESS = "1";

    /// <summary>
    /// 1 : Success
    /// 0 : Fail 
    /// Maybe you can use Enum to set ResultCode.
    /// </summary>        
    public string ResultCode { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Exception message
    /// </summary>         
    public string ResultMessage { get; set; }


}
```

**Catch Exception**

> Use code in try catch block and catch exception.Send data to view using any data transfer method ( ViewBag , vs vs ) or using jsonResult

```
 OperationResult resultData = new OperationResult();

    try
    {
      if (model.buildingID == 0)
      {
        var result = objAddBuildingBusinessModel.AddBuilding(model, connectionstring,isUnique);                       
      }
      else
      {
        var result = objAddBuildingBusinessModel.UpdateBuilding(model, connectionstring);
      }
      //resultData.ResultCode = OperationResult.SUCCESS;
      resultData.ResultCode = (int)OperationEnum.SUCCESS;
      resultData.ResultMessage = "Opetaion Success";
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
       //resultData.ResultCode = OperationResult.FAIL;
       resultData.ResultCode = (int)OperationEnum.FAIL;
       resultData.ResultMessage = ex.Message;
    }
   // return resultData on viewBag or andy transafer data to view 
    ViewBag.ResultData = resultData;
```

**Show Exception**

> Best practice get operation value to Enum ( success or fail )
>   You can use as examples hardcode or use enum value if use enum value
>   so that you can reach through the same enum values ​​on both sides

```
if ('@ViewBag.ResultData.ResultCode' ==  '@(int)OperationEnum.FAIL') // or "2"
{
    var exMessage = '@ViewBag.ResultData.ResultMessage';
    alert(exMessage );
}
```

Comment: but how do I do it with the help of enum.. And what is OperationResult.SUCCESS means ? Can you please elaborate.

Comment: I updated answer. I use operation property in OperationResult class
You can use in this way or use enum value if use enum value so that you can reach through the same enum values ​​on both sides

Comment: I added enum class

Comment: Ok great .. But should I include that model in the view also. The OperationResult model ? If so how to do it. Iam new to these concepts. Please help

Comment: if you access to any model  in cshtml you can add model nameSpace  
@ using YourNameSpace or @ using YourNameSpace.Folder  to top page  in cshtml.

Comment: This is my code now. But it is not redirecting to the view page.if (model.buildingID == 0)
                {
      var result = objAddBuildingBusinessModel.AddBuilding(model, connectionstring,isUnique);
                    if(result==false)
                   {
                       resultData.ResultCode = OperationResult.FAIL;
                       resultData.ResultMessage = "Operation Failed";
                       ViewBag.Result = resultData;
                      // return RedirectToAction("~/AddBuilding", "ConfigLocationController");
                     }

Answer (score 1):

Store **result** output in **viewbag** and on view side check viewbag value and show error message:

**Note:** ViewBag will hold your variable for single view request

**Controller:**

```
ViewBag.Result=result;
```

**View:**

```
@if(ViewBag.Result)
{
    //Eroor Message HTML
}
```

**JQuery/Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if (String('@ViewBag.Result').toUpperCase() == "TRUE")
    {
        alert('Error Message');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

first use Viewbag

```
 ViewBag.ans = "result";
```

then in the model section

```
  @model IEnumerable<MVCApp.Models.ModelName>
<b>Result:</b> @ViewBag.ans<br />
```